# What's the difference between a Nissan Terrano II R50 and L50? Which do I own?

Tags: nissan, pathfinder

I own a 1996 Nissan Terrano 2, 2.7 liter diesel engine, manual transmission. When I try to order parts from Japan, the various sites ask me whether I own an R50 or L50. All the mechanical specs match for both. I can't figure out what the difference is and which one I own. It may be right hand vs left hand drive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find an L50 designation for the second generation Terrano.  The body was the R50 series.

Nissan body designation L50 is for the 2012- Infinity QX60

L50 also refers to a Nissan paint code color of "chocolate brown"

HTH